# How can I get the singular points of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Consider a complex function as follows:
$$
f(z)=\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2-4}+2c}{2z(z+\sqrt{z^2-4})-2c\beta^{-1}}
$$
where $Re(z)\in [-2, 2]$, $c$ and $\beta$ are two positive constants.

How can I get the singular points of this function?

My idea is to simplify the denominator and solve the root but this is complicated...

---

I try to multiply $[(2z^2-2c\beta^{-1})-2z\sqrt{z^2-4}]$ on the denominator and numerator and I get
$$
f(z)=\frac{[z+\sqrt{z^2-4}+2c][(2z^2-2c\beta^{-1})-2z\sqrt{z^2-4}]}{(16-8c\beta^{-1})z^2+4c^2\beta^{-2}}=\frac{1}{(16-8c\beta^{-1})}\frac{[z+\sqrt{z^2-4}+2c][(2z^2-2c\beta^{-1})-2z\sqrt{z^2-4}]}{(z-\sqrt{\frac{c^2\beta^{-1}}{2c\beta^{-1}-4}
})(z+\sqrt{\frac{c^2\beta^{-1}}{2c\beta^{-1}-4}
})}
$$

But we cannot ensure $\frac{c^2\beta^{-1}}{2c\beta^{-1}-4}\ge 0$...